# Negation of regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I want to find all the values which are not in the given format

123-45-6789

123 45 6789

123-456789

12345-6789

12345 6789

123 456789

So i wrote the regex which matches the above format so I need the negation of the expression to solve myproblem

```
(\b\d{3}(\s?)\d{2}(\s?)\d{4}\b)|(\b\d{3}(|-)\d{2}(|-)\d{4}\b)
```

Comment: How it is used? What are the valid formats to match? Add code

Comment: i have edited the question, hope this explains the problem

Comment: Try simple regex `^\d{3}[ -]?\d{2}[ -]?\d{4}$`  and `/yourLongRegexHere/.test(myStr) === false` to negate the regex result

Comment: i tried testing your regex online but its not solving the problem

Answer (score 2):

There's a negative lookaround: (?! your_pattern )

In your case it is:

```
(?!(\b\d{3}(\s?)\d{2}(\s?)\d{4}\b)|(\b\d{3}(|-)\d{2}(|-)\d{4}\b))
```

UPDATE: it doesn't work in JS, since it has reduced Regex syntax support. So you can't use some types of lookup. Then your only chance is to do

```
if (! your_regex.test(your_str) ) { /* work with unmatched strings */ }
```

Comment: @diziaq: You could clean the regex to show more effort since you got 2 upvotes. It is clear the alternation can be avoided here. And I guess OP needs start/end string anchors for it to work.

Comment: @stribizhev, absolutely agree with you. I tried to keep the original regex inside to avoid the author's confusion. And it's not clear for me what the problem he's solving. Oops... and now I see the author is messing around with JavaScript... Let me update.